# How can I make an image in a div responsive?

Tags: html, css

What I want is for the image to scale down as the browser window scales. Would making it a background image be a better solution?

```
#home-feature5 {
    height:618px; 
    width:1210px; 
    position:relative;
}
.photo {
    bottom: 37px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 20px;
}

.photo img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.bg {
    background-color:#f88b5c; 
    width:100%;
    height:95px;
    bottom:0; 
    left:0;
    position:absolute;  
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9LLr7m6w/

Comment: You need to use background with `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should make the whole site responsive:

```
#home-feature5 {
height:618px; 
width:1210px; 
position:relative;
max-width: 100%;
```

}

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LLr7m6w/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Set the width attribute of the image as a percentage instead of fixing it. Doing so, it should be able to scale accordingly.

For example, let’s say you have an image that has a natural size of 1210px x 618px  in a 1400px wide document. Below 1400px, the document will be fluid. The calculation of how much width the image takes up as a percentage of the document is easy: (1210 / 1400 ) × 100 = 86.43%

Answer (score 0):

When I want the image to scale down with the page I do something like this.

```
body{
  width=100%;
}
#home-feature5 {
    height:618px; 
    width:1210px;      //might want to change this to a percentage 
    position:relative;
}
.photo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    width:50%;         //the div will be 50% of its container (#home-feature5)
}
.photo img {
    width:100%;        // will be 100% of its container (.photo)  
}

<!-- with html something like this -->

<div id="#home-feature5">
  <div class="photo">
    <img alt="whatever missing" src="whatever.png">
  </div>
</div>
```